# too many values to unpack (expected 2) after merge

Tags: python, pandas, left-join

I'm having issues with too many values to unpack (expected 2) after running merge.

```
menu_df.columns=['id','category','name','description','price']
menu_df.columns

Index(['id', 'category', 'name', 'description', 'price'], dtype='object')
```

```
ue_df_c.columns
Index(['id', 'position', 'name', 'score', 'ratings', 'category', 'price_range',
       'full_address', 'zip_code', 'lat', 'lng', 'state', 'food_cat_1',
       'food_cat_2'],
      dtype='object')
```

```
uec_menu_df=ue_df_c.merge(menu_df, on='id', suffixes=('_ue,_menu'))
print(uec_menu_df.head(10))
.....
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well as the full stacktrace.

Comment: The error is from the merge function?

Comment: I think it is because you have specified your suffixes incorrectly. Try `("_ue", "_menu")`

Answer (score 0):

Here Suffixes parameter should be a tuple with two elements, so basically '_ue' be used as suffix to the columns from the 'ue_df_c' dataframe and '_menu' will be used as suffix to the columns from the 'menu_df' dataframe.

please change your code to this to solve the error

```
uec_menu_df=ue_df_c.merge(menu_df, on='id', suffixes=('_ue','_menu'))
```